# Equivalence of cycles in homology group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$.$\sigma_1:t\mapsto (t,0), \sigma_2:t\mapsto (0,t),\sigma:t\to(t,t)$. We know that $H_1(X) = \langle [\sigma_1],[\sigma_2]\rangle$. I want to prove that $[\sigma_1+\sigma_2] = [\sigma]$ i.e. there is $\theta \in H_2(X)$ such $\partial\theta = \theta(t,0) + \theta(0,t) -\theta(1-t,t) = \sigma_1+\sigma_2-\sigma$. But i have troubles with finding such $\theta$.

Comment: You should draw a picture of the torus as a square with the two sides identified, and then draw what these cycles are in the torus.

Comment: I draw a picture, but obtain $\theta(x,y) = (y,-x)$ and there is problem with sign on face (t,0).